# Query from multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table named Fruits.

```
ID English Spanish German
1  Apple   Applice Apple-
2  Orange  --      --
```

If the program passes 1 and English, I have to return 'Apple'. How could I write the sql query for that? Thank you.

Comment: Is the program returning a string that is the sql query? you may want to include the program part in your question.

Comment: Hi, I just need to return the correct column name , Eg. Select English from Fruits where ID=1 , but if the program passes Spanish the query should be Select Spanish From Fruits, I don't know how to dynamically select the column. Thanks

Comment: Since you want to query on data such as `English` or `Spanish`, that's a good indicator that your table design is wrong. Things that you want to query on ought to be *values* that exist *within* rows of data - not in the *names* of columns. The table ought to be `ID, Language, FruitName` and have one row for each `Language`, for each `ID`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
    ID,
    case @Lang
        when 'English' then English 
        when 'Spanish' then Spanish
    end as Name
from Fruits
where ID = @ID;
```

or, if you have more than one column to choose, you can use apply so you don't have to write multiple case statements

```
select
    F.ID,
    N.Name,
    N.Name_Full
from Fruits as F
    outer apply (values
        ('English', F.English, F.English_Full),
        ('Spanish', F.Spanish, F.Spanish_Full)
    ) as N(lang, Name, Name_Full)
where F.ID = @ID and N.lang = @lang
```

Answer (score 2):

Fisrt you should normalize database, to support multilanguage, this means split the table in 2

tables:

1. `Fruit` (FruitID, *GenericName*, etc)
2. `Languages` (LanguageID, LanguageName, etc)
3. `FruitTranslations` (FruitID, LanguageID, LocalizedName)

then the query will be just a simple query to table FruitTranslations...

---

If you still want a query for this then you can use Dynamic SQL,

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Cmd = 'SELECT ' + @Language + 
           ' FROM Fruits WHERE ID = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Id) + ''''
EXEC(@Cmd)
```

Comment: this way is subject to sql injection

Comment: I'd rather not use dynamic for this task, especially if @lang is entered by user

Comment: @ArabicProgrammer indeed it could be subject to sql injection, this could be avoided 1. if you check that `@Language` is a valid column against `sys.tables inner join sys.columns...`, 2 check that the `@Languague` is just one word, 3. `@ID` is `INT` Anyway the main point of my answer was the normalization part.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @Lang VARCHAR(10) = 'English'
    , @ID INT = 1

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '
SELECT ' + @Lang + ' 
FROM dbo.Fruits 
WHERE ID = ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(4))

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: this way is subject to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using stored procedures because in stored procedures you can use 'if else' condition. ex:

```
@ID as int,@Lang as varchar(50)

if @Lang = 'English'
 begin
    select ID,English from Fruits where ID = @ID;
 end
else
  if @Lang = 'Spanish'
 begin
    select ID,Spanish from Fruits where ID = @ID;
 end
```

...